# Custom Search using jQuery Currently Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a listings table and in that table there is a square_feet column. I am trying to build a filter so I can enter the low end and the high end of a square footage range and then have those results display on the page and hide the rest. This JS is being used with Rails 4. Currently, when I enter a value regardless of which field, it just removes all of the listings.

jQuery:

```
// min square footage
var minSquareFootage = $.trim($("#min-square-footage").val());
if (minSquareFootage.length > 0) {
   var minSquareFootage = parseFloat(minSquareFootageVal);
   rows = rows.filter(function(i, v) {
      var rowSquareFeet = $(this).data("square_feet");
      return rowSquareFeet >= minSquareFootage;
   });
}

// max square footage
var maxSquareFootage = $.trim($("#max-square-footage").val());
if (maxSquareFootage.length > 0) {
   var maxSquareFootage = parseFloat(maxSquareFootageVal);
   rows = rows.filter(function(i, v) {
      var rowSquareFeet = $(this).data("square_feet");
      return rowSquareFeet >= maxSquareFootage;
   });
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Min Sq Ft" id="min-square-footage">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Max Sq Ft" id="max-square-footage">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure this is fully where the problem lies, but it would seem like you would want rowSquareFeet **<=** maxSquareFootage in the second filter callback.